# Display WPF (XAML) hierarchical data without TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Is there an equivalent to `ItemsControl` for hierarchical data *(arbitrary depth)*?**

I want to avoid `TreeView` or such controls that offer expand/collapse/select functionality. I also don't want to fight against the default control implementations and re-template them writing pages of XAML.

*PS: What I want can be done in code but I'd rather use the nice templates in XAML and type less.*

Comment: How would what you want to do be accomplished in code? One option might be to implement in code, and then find how to back that code into a custom style or template in XAML

Comment: @Hugo In code it's really easy as you can use a recursive function. I'm not sure how that can be done in XAML without the TreeView.

Comment: What I meant was, would you add children to a collection of the object, grandchildren to the child's children collection, and so on? If so, your template could have it's own `ItemsControl` and offset the `Margin` to make it indented, bound to the children collection.